# get no result when using --js-flags in Google Chrome on android

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, v8

I need to get some js heap/GC infomation when chrome is doing some page-loading work in Android. I followed the instructions from [running chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/). I added the tags like that:

adb shell: echo chrome --no-sandbox --js-flags=\"--logfile=/data/local/tmp/v8.log --noprof-lazy --prof_auto --trace_gc\"> /data/local/content-shell-command-line

However, when checking the command line by "chrome://version", I found it failed in adding flags. I tried to revise the file into /data/local/chrome-command-line and then it worked.

However, after the data collection (on both chrome 28 and chrome 29 beta), I found there was no gc/heap detailed infomation collected in Android logcat as well as v8.log(it just showed the ticks gc took and its proportion in total ticks).

When using d8 with --tace_gc tag, it can give the outputs below in stdout. Thus, ideally, chrome runing with flag:"--tace_gc" should give the same output.

13040]    35009 ms: Mark-sweep 66.4 (78.6) -> 41.7 (74.5) MB, 1 / 28.6 ms (+ 123.9 ms in 202 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.1 ms) [StackGuard GC request] [GC in old space requested].

[13040]    35089 ms: Scavenge 45.7 (74.5) -> 41.8 (74.5) MB, 0.6 ms [Runtime::PerformGC].

[13040]    35171 ms: Scavenge 45.8 (74.5) -> 42.0 (74.5) MB, 0.6 ms [Runtime::PerformGC].

[13040]    35279 ms: Scavenge 46.0 (74.5) -> 42.5 (74.5) MB, 2.7 ms [Runtime::PerformGC].

[13040]    35359 ms: Scavenge 46.1 (74.5) -> 42.6 (74.5) MB, 3.3 ms [Runtime::PerformGC].

I am not sure if i missed something or made any mistakes when set the flags, anyone can kindly help? 
Thanks so much.